# JPA and contains

Tags: jpa

I have a plain JPA Entity with the ID-Attribute generated:

```
@Entity(name = "AUTO_COMPLETION")
public class AutoCompletion extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "aip_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "aip_seq", sequenceName = "aip_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

...

}
```

I create an JPA Entity:

```
    AutoCompletion c2a1 = new AutoCompletion();
    c2a1.setClient(c2);
    c2a1.setText("c2a1");
    c2a1.setType(AutoCompletionType.PERSON);
    autoCompletionService.create(c1a1);
```

Create is implemented as follows:

```
@Override
public T create(final T t) {
    this.em.persist(t);
    return t;
}
```

Now the entity gets an written into the database along with the ID-Attribute set. I want to retrieve it again by a function:

```
List<AutoCompletion> completions = autoCompletionService.getAutoCompletions()
```

I thought I could call

```
completions.contains(c2a1)
```

but it always returns false... I don't understand why. Shouldn't it return true?

Comment: Have you implemented equals method?

Comment: no its default. But I thought the entitymanger would take care

Comment: Which JPA provider are you using? Can you see which is the List implementation returned by the method?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to implement hashCode and equals

Answer (score 0):

The object you created when you persist and the object retrieved will always not be the equal. Yes they are logically equal since they pertain to the same row in the DB, but they are different object references and point to different locations in memory.

See javadoc for [List.contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29). It uses equals method of your class to compare. Since you have not overriden the equals method, this will default obj1 == obj2 to operation, which will return true only if they point to the same location in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You would get the same entity instance only if the calls were done in the same transaction. I guess that's not your case, you're calling service classes and you probably don't have a transaction scope bigger than service.

As others have already suggested, `equals()` an `hashcode()` need to be implemented in order for `List#contains()` to work like you expect it. This might or might not have consequences on the rest of your code, it should be analyzed.